# Javascript - how to echo php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I echo php inside javascript correctly?

```
var timeDiff = 60-20;
if ( timeDiff <= 60 ) {
   var stamp = timeDiff <?php echo $this->__('second ago') . '.'; ?>;
}
```

Console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

It does echo out 'second ago' in chromes Sources, followed by the error though.

Comment: var stamp = timeDiff +'<?php echo $this->__('second ago') . '.'; ?>';

Comment: you need to enclose it in `''`(like a string literal) - not sure abt PHP syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544648/echo-php-inside-javascript

Comment: In this kind of situation it is useful to "view source" in your browser to see what the PHP ends up outputting into your javascript.  That way you can see more easily what the problems are.

Comment: @Nabil : Sandeep Pal's code will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrapping the content you are echoing out with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should do the trick, e.g.

```
var stamp = timeDiff <?php echo json_encode($this->__('second ago') . '.'); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var timeDiff = 60-20;
if ( timeDiff <= 60 ) {
    var stamp = timeDiff + <?php=($this->__('second ago'))?>;
}
```